# Visual Studio 2015 update 3 - throwing vcruntime140.dll exception

Tags: visual-c++

I am using Visual studio 2015 update 3 on windows 10.0.10586.0.

I am getting an exception while debugging:

> shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp(14267)\COMDLG32.dll!00007FFBC2162EFB:
>   (caller: 00007FFBC2196BC1) ReturnHr(1) tid(5c8) 80004005 Unspecified
>   error

followed by

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA16D4C595 (vcruntime140.dll) in
>   3dsmax.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x000002EBE7F18000

followed by

> Unloaded 'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\3ds Max 2018\en-US\MC3Res.dll' 
>   Unloaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscordacwks.dll'

I put the vcruntime140.dll in the folder where my exe is. but does not work.
I have checked memcpy function, it is copying right data from source to destination. Do i need to register this particular dll? Or this is a memory overflow issue and how to solve it? I am unable to recognize. Please help.

Comment: Most likely case of memory overflow. `Access violation reading location 0x000002EBE7F18000`. Please check your code.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest me the solution for other exceptions?